# How to wrap text in table when using itemize in it?

Tags: tables, itemize

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
    \hline
         & ABO & CPI Project & PEA & PM & VSM \\
    \hline
    Acronym & Activity based operation & Continuous Process Improvement Project & Process Excellence Assessment & Process Mapping & Value Stream Mapping \\
    \hline
    Method & \begin{itemize}
        \item Interviews with every single role with operations department
        \item Final presentation/documentation
        \item of effort starting from level 1 down to level 3
        \item Improvement potential
    \end{itemize} & Lean Six Sigma approach. Workshop together with SME's and Case by Case \begin{itemize}
        \item PMQ
        \item Process Owner
        \item IT
        \item Compliance
        \item tbd
    \end{itemize} & Interview with every local process owner together with local PMQ & Workshop together with SME's and Case by Case \begin{itemize}
        \item 
    \end{itemize}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: (1) please always make full but minimal examples that others can copy and test as is, not a sniplet like this where we have to add code. (2) What is your intention here? The `center` env does nothing in relation to `longtable` and you explicitly ask for columns that are `1cm` wide.

Comment: Please start by explaining what your goal is. And explain why the columns are 1cm the text will never fit

Comment: Also consider if anyone would even like to read data presented this way? Even in landscape with 4cm cols it is hard to read.

Comment: The 1cm you see is i was trying several different measurement in order to fit the text in the table. I am trying to create a table of 6*8 . I tried specifiying the size as 1.5cm for each column but the text in the itemize goes into the second coloumn and does not comes up in a single column as a result of which the text gets mixed up with the text in 3rd column

Comment: And I keep telling you there is not enough room and thus things bleed into other columns. Redesign.

Comment: That is what i am asking help for. I am not sure how do i design it